# Electricity not working when car is off

Tags: electrical, obd-ii, accord, lights, obd

2015 Honda Accord

Replaced the battery in my wife's car.  After replacing the battery, it seems as though none of these things work when the car is off - Headlights, Dome light, Power locks, key fob (tried both the regular and backup fob).

When you turn the car on, all of these things work totally fine.

Not sure where to look to solve the problem.

Edit:  When replacing the battery, I used one of those memory savers plugged into the OBD2 port.  Had it plugged into the 12v cigarette lighter of my other car for the power source.  I just discovered that I can't get power to the OBD2 port, even when the car is on.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘car is off’?  Ignition off or engine not running?

Comment: Ignition is off.  No key in ignition.

Comment: Is this to say that before you replaced the battery all these accessories were working with no key in the ignition?

Comment: Correct.  Everything was fine prior to the battery change.

Comment: Are there multiple wires connected to the battery post connector?  Are all of them still connected?

Comment: I will double check tonight, but I seem to remember it only being the post connector and that's it.

Comment: Confirmed - no extra wires on battery posts and all wires are connected.

Comment: Have you checked all of the fuses?

Comment: Just checked the fuses and the ones where I was able to squeeze my tester in to check looked good.

Comment: How did you test them without taking them out?

Comment: Touched the prongs to the exposed metal at the top of the fuse.  Wouldn't that work?  We can come back to this step.  Assuming the fuses are ok - anything else I can try?

Comment: You really can’t reliably check fuses in circuit. Did you use the resistance setting on a multimeter?  I will have to find a wiring schematic to diagnose further.  Do you have one?

Comment: I have a tester that lights up if the fuse is good when you touch both ends.  I don't have a wiring schematic and I can't find one online unfortunately.  Take it to the shop at this point?

Comment: Edit:  When replacing the battery, I used one of those memory savers plugged into the OBD2 port.  Had it plugged into the 12v cigarette lighter of my other car for the power source.  I just discovered that I can't get power to the OBD2 port, even when the car is on.  I'm not sure if that had anything to do with it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this ended up being a blown fuse, as expected.  #21 under the hood.  Labeled in the owner's manual as "Back Up". 10 Amp.  The shop I took it to was nice enough to include a big print out of all of the functions for each fuse, and all of the things broken were connected to this fuse.  Couldn't find any detailed information on the internet for this, and it could have saved me a lot of time and 110 bucks.  Oh well.  Glad I have the info now for all of the fuses and their functions.